# Yarn using link has different performance than install package?

Tags: performance, npm, yarnpkg, npm-link

I have written a plugin for prettier and try to increase the speed of the formatter.
So I used `yarn link` + `yarn link "@prettier/plugin-pug"` and run `yarn prettier --write 'src/**/*.pug'` in a (closed source) project with 86 pug files

When I don't link my plugin and use the default installed via package.json,
I get a result around `✨ Done in 18s`

When I use the same commit + build the dist + yarn link,
I get a result around `✨ Done in 8s`

Can someone explain whats going on?
Is it because the linked version has it's own node_modules folder?

<strike>I have not tested it with npm, but I think it might be the same result.</strike>
It's the same result when using npm link!